# Recommended rule to download maven artifacts into repository (maven_install vs jvm_import_external)

Tags: bazel

What is the recommended way to download dependencies from maven. There are three ways to currently do this (mvn_jar is deprecated). Is the future maven_install (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external) or jvm_import_external (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/build_defs/repo/jvm.bzl)?

Answer (score 3):

Author of `rules_jvm_external` here.

Both `jvm_import_external` and `maven_install` are valid and supported ways for fetching Maven artifacts. They also serve different use cases and styles: `jvm_import_external` does not do transitive dependency resolution, so it can be use for finer-grained artifact handling if you don't wish to use `maven_install`.

In general, use `maven_install` to skip the tedious work of managing transitive dependencies, and `jvm_import_external` if you want more manual control over your Maven dependencies.